# How to play particles for a specific cloned game object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

I am now making a simple game in Unity. There are cones falling from the sky and player needs to control a cube to dodge them. When a cone hit the cube, it decreases the cube's HP and emit some particles. Here is my script :

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour{

ParticleSystem particle;

static move instance;

void Start()
{
    particle = FindObjectOfType<ParticleSystem>();
    instance = this;
}

public static void PlayParticles()
{
    instance.particle.Play();
}
}
```

Second:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("cone"))
    {
        move.PlayParticles();
        GameDirector.DecreaseHp(0.25f);

    }

}
```

The first script is attached to the cone prefab and the second one is attached to the cube. But the problem is that when a cone hit the cube, other cones emit particles instead of the cone that hit the cube.
How can I solve the problem?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: By not using a `static` (abuse Singleton pattern)? And by not using `FindObjectOfType` but rather `GetComponent` ... What is your `ParticleSystem` attached to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove cone-related logic from cube:

   private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
   {
       if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("cone"))
       {
           // move.PlayParticles();  //------------ remove this line
           GameDirector.DecreaseHp(0.25f);
       }

   }
2. Make particle variable assignable in inspector - add [SerializeField] attribute. And assign it in inspector.
3. Add collision processing into your cone script.
4. Remove unnecessary statics from script.

Something like this:

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] //------- Add attribute and do not forget to assign PS in inspector
ParticleSystem particle;

//static move instance; //----- Remove

//Remove Start:
/*
    void Start()
    {
        particle = FindObjectOfType<ParticleSystem>();
        instance = this;
    }
*/
//Remove PlayParticles:
/*
    public void PlayParticles()
    {
        Change:
        instance.particle.Play();
    }
*/
    //---- Add collision check
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("cube")) //----- Set proper tag to your cube
        {
            particle.Play();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you are (ab!)using the Singleton pattern for everything and call a lot of things `static` that should rather be instanced methods/properties.

---

So assuming each prefab has your `move` script and also the `ParticleSystem` somewhere in its own Hierarchy you could rather do

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Already reference this via the Inspector by dragging the 
    // GameObject with the ParticleSystem into this slot
    [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem particle;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // As fallback get it on runtime
        if(!particle) particle = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>(true);
    }

    // Use a normal instanced method
    public void PlayParticles()
    {
        particle.Play();
    }
}
```

And then get the instance from the collision:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("cone"))
    {
        // Get the instance of the component
        var moveInstance = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<move>();
        if(!moveInstance)
        {
             Debug.LogError($"There is no {nameof(move)} component attached to the colliding object {collision.gameObject.name}!", this);   
        }
        else
        {
            // call the method of this instance
            moveInstance.PlayParticles();
        }
        GameDirector.DecreaseHp(0.25f);
    }
}
```

---

But it seems like you could also let your Player directly itself handle the entire thing. Rather attach the particle system to it instead and put `move` on the Player (cube) like

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Already reference this via the Inspector by dragging the 
    // GameObject with the ParticleSystem into this slot
    [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem particle;

    void Start()
    {
        if(!particle) particle = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>(true);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("cone"))
        {
            particle.Play();
            GameDirector.DecreaseHp(0.25f);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Note**: It probably would be the same for the `GameDirector` and you should rather have a field

```
[SerilaizeField] private GameDirector gameDirector;
```

and either reference this via the Inspector or (**only as fallback**) get it on runtime via

```
private void Awake()
{
    if(!gameDirector) gameDirector = FindObjectOfType<GameDirector>();
}
```

here `FindObjectOfType` seems to be "ok" since `GameDirector` sounds like something existing only exactly **once** in the scene.